# Inputting Python List into SQLite

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I'm trying to add the list that is made after it parses through each line. As I go through each code I get different errors

```
(C:\Users\myname\Desktop\pythonCourse>dblesson2
Enter file name: mbox.txt
['uct.ac.za']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\pythonCourse\dblesson2.py", line 25, in      
    <module>
    #VALUES ( ?, 1 )''', ( email, ) )
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "#VALUES": syntax error)
```

and I know that it is because I am not passing the correct data to the database but I can't figure this out on my own.

```
import sqlite
import re

conn = sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (email TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: ') : continue
    line = line.rstrip()
    email = re.findall('@(\S+[a-zA-Z]+)', line)
    print email
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE email = ? ', (email))
    row = cur.fetchone()
if row is None:
    #cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (email, count) 
        #VALUES ( ?, 1 )''', ( email, ) )
else : 
    cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count=count+1 WHERE email = ?', 
        (email, ))
# This statement commits outstanding changes to disk each 
# time through the loop - the program can be made faster 
# by moving the commit so it runs only after the loop completes
conn.commit()

# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT email, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

print
print "Counts:"
for row in cur.execute(sqlstr) :
print str(row[0]), row[1]

cur.close()`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please clarify what the problem is? "I get different errors" is not very helpful. Post those errors! Please take a moment to read through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of small errors in your program. Let me try to list them:

- `re.findall` returns a list, but you seem to treat it as a single string. Try `email = email[0]` to only consider the first element of the list.
- Your first `SELECT` statement has `(email)`. Putting a single item inside parentheses does not make it a tuple. Try `(email,)` or `[email]` instead.
- The `if` after the `for` loop is meant to occur for each iteration of the `for` loop, so it must be indented by one stop.
- The body of the `if` cannot be empty. Either uncomment that operation, or change it to `pass`.
- The body of your final `for` loop needs to be indented one stop.
- As a courtesy to Stack Overflow readers, please copy-paste entire stand-alone programs, not merely snippets.

Here is the your program after I fixed the problems:

```
import sqlite3
import re

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Counts''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Counts (email TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

fname = raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if ( len(fname) < 1 ) : fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname)
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith('From: ') : continue
    line = line.rstrip()
    email = re.findall('@(\S+[a-zA-Z]+)', line)
    email = email[0]
    cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE email = ? ', (email,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is None:
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Counts (email, count) 
            VALUES ( ?, 1 )''', ( email, ) )
    else : 
        cur.execute('UPDATE Counts SET count=count+1 WHERE email = ?', 
            (email, ))
# This statement commits outstanding changes to disk each 
# time through the loop - the program can be made faster 
# by moving the commit so it runs only after the loop completes
conn.commit()

# https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html
sqlstr = 'SELECT email, count FROM Counts ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

print
print "Counts:"
for row in cur.execute(sqlstr) :
    print str(row[0]), row[1]

cur.close()
```

Comment: This is why I love this community for helpful people like yourself! I am going to read and reread your comment to understand this more fully. I appreciate your time that you have spent to help me understand this problem. Hopefully in the future I can extend myself the same way you have today. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('emaildb.sqlite')
cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS counts''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

f_name=raw_input('Enter file name: ')
if len(f_name)<1   :   f_name='mbox.txt'
fn=open(f_name)
for line in fn:
   if not line.startswith('From: ') : continue 
   words = line.split()
   email=words[1]
   domain=email.split('@')
   organiz=domain[1]
   print organiz
   cur.execute('SELECT count FROM Counts WHERE org=?',(organiz, ))
   row=cur.fetchone()
   if row==None:
     cur.execute('''INSERT INTO counts (org, count) VALUES (?,1)''',
     (organiz, ))
   else:
     cur.execute('''UPDATE counts SET count=count+1 WHERE org=?''',(organiz, 
     ))
conn.commit()
```